# Having trouble installing Racoon and Strongswan on the same system

Tags: ubuntu, ipsec, package-management, strongswan, racoon

I have two applications that I need to run, one uses Racoon for establishing IPSec tunnels and the other uses Strongswan. Therefore, I need both Racoon and Strongswan installed simultaneously on my Ubuntu 12.04 box. However, when I install Strongswan it removes Racoon, and vice versa. How do I install one without removing the other?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't. Put them on different machines, or fix one or both applications.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the applications, as I don't have access to the source of either. What I'm trying to do is emulate a network from this ubuntu box where some routers use strongswan and some use racoon. Some sort of workaround would be helpful as well, if there are any for a situation like this.

Comment: Hey, same here, do you find a workaround?

Comment: Nope. If I remember correctly, I had to contact the creators of one of the applications and have the switch so that all routers were using the same software :(.